# How to calculate intersection of two surfaces in parametric form

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces

I am given the two surfaces
$$S_1(s,r) = \left( 2\sin r \cdot (e^{s/2}-1)+r, s, e^{s/2}\cdot\sin r \right )$$
and
$$S_2(s,r) = (r, s+r, 0)$$
and am asked to find the intersection $S_1\cap S_2$.

I can see that whatever the intersection is, its third coordinate must be $0$. So, $r$ and $s$ must satisfy
$$e^{s/2}\cdot\sin r = 0 \implies r=k\pi$$
But, I can't understand how to proceed anymore from here.

In general, I would like to know how to calculate the intersection of the surfaces
$$S_1 (r,s) = \left (f_1(r,s), g_1(r,s), h_1(r,s)\right)$$
and
$$S_2 (r,s) = \left (f_2(r,s), g_2(r,s), h_2(r,s)\right)$$
where $f_i,g_i,h_i$ are continuous functions.

Comment: You found out that $\sin r=0\,.$ This simplifies $S_1$ to $(k\pi,s,0)\,.$ Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general method apart from equating each coordinate. In the present case, the most "restrictive" equation is provided by the second coordinate, namely $s = s+r$, hence $r = 0$. In consequence, the first and third equations are satisfied straighforwardly, since they vanish automatically when $r = 0$. Thus, the parameter $s$ remains free and the intersection domain is given by
$$
S_1 \cap S_2 = \{(0,s,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \;|\; s \in \mathbb{R}\},
$$
which is nothing else than the "$y$-axis".